# C program example2

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  int a, j;
  for (a = 5; a < 15; a++) {
    for (j = 1; j < 10; j++) {

      if (j > a) {
        break;
      }
    }
    printf("%d\n", j);
  }

  getch();
}
```

output:

```
6
7
8
9
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

I'm just trying to clear some points; correct me if I'm wrong, so in the above code: In the first loop when ***a=5*** the internal ***for*** loop runs from ***j=1 to j=6*** when ***j>a*** becomes true it encounters ***break*** and value of ***j*** is set to ***6*** which is printed. This goes on for ***a=6,7,8..***. But what happens when "a=9" ? I've set ***j<10*** but in the ***output*** i get an output of 10 when ***j=9 or higher***. Can someone explain this to me please.

Comment: `void main` is wrong. Use `int main()`.

Comment: Suppose, "a" equals 9. Ok. Then your program enters the second for-loop "for(j=1;j<10;j++)" which will break when the condotion - j<10 - no longer applys. which means: It will end when "j" hits 10. Obviously for a equals 9 "if(j>a)" will never trigger, since the for-loop "for(j=1;j<10;j++)" ends and wont enter its body for "j" = 10.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, `void main()` is wrong. Use `int main()`. Secondly, when `j == 9`, the loop body is executed and then `j` is incremented once, which makes it `10`, then `j < 10` is `false`, thus the `for` loop is terminated and the `printf("%d\n", j);` part is executed, which prints the value of `j`, which is `10`.

Answer (score 1):

as you said you ,you have set `j<10` so when `j==10` your condition is false.I mean `j` become `10` so `j<10` is false and you will exit this loop `for (j = 1; j < 10; j++)` and print `j=10` this keep happening while `a<15` and then program ends.

Answer (score -1):

Let's look at the code generated by the GCC compiler for the following piece of code

```
int main() {

    int x;

    for(x = 1; x < 10; ++x)
        ;

    return 0;
}
```

-

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $1, -4(%rbp)
        jmp     .L2
.L3:
        addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L2:
        cmpl    $9, -4(%rbp)
        jle     .L3             <---------------
        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

We can see that it tests if the `x` variable is `<= 9` so it increments it to 10 when it's 9 because the condition is true

Comment: You don't need the assembler for that. The definition of `for` is sufficient. The assembler conforms to that definition.

Comment: Yeah, let's all write code without knowing how it works.